# Plotting asymptotically constant functions

Tags: plotting

Can anyone explain why Mathematica struggles with the following (equivalent) plots?

```
Plot[x Abs[Sqrt[0.0002^2 - x^2] - Sqrt[0.0001^2 - x^2]], {x, 1000, 
  10000}]
Plot[x^2 Abs[Sqrt[0.0002^2/x^2 - 1] - Sqrt[0.0001^2/x^2 - 1]], {x, 
  1000, 10000}]
```

I'm getting very 'random' behaviour for a function which should approach a constant asymptotically. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just seeing numerical precision issues when working with machine numbers. Using higher precision will fix this. In order to use higher precision, you need to make sure the function to be plotted is exact, so the following should produce your expected output:

```
Plot[
    x Abs[Sqrt[(2/10000)^2-x^2] - Sqrt[(1/10000)^2-x^2]],
    {x,1000,10000},
    WorkingPrecision->20
]
```

[image]

and similarly for the other example.

Answer (score 0):

You only use the expression `Abs[Sqrt[0.0002^2 - x^2] - Sqrt[0.0001^2 - x^2]]` at `1000<x<10000`. In this domain, the expression `Sqrt[0.0002^2 - x^2] - Sqrt[0.0001^2 - x^2]` is purely imaginary, and you can help Mma by rewriting your expression identically:

```
Abs[Sqrt[0.0002^2 - x^2] - Sqrt[0.0001^2 - x^2]]≡Sqrt[x^2 - 0.0002^2] - Sqrt[x^2 - 0.0001^2]
```

After that you get the following statement:

```
Plot[x Sqrt[x^2 - 0.0002^2] - Sqrt[x^2 - 0.0001^2], {x, 1000, 10000}]
```

yielding

[image]

The same takes place with the second plot.

Have fun!

Comment: But the x at the front multiplies the whole expression. When I do this with your new plot, I still get the random looking behaviour.

Comment: I obtained the plot shown above. If you do not, you may have problems outside of Mma.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch what is this rule / identity $$| \sqrt{c_1-x^2}-\sqrt{c_2-x^2}| =\sqrt{x^2-c_2}-\sqrt{x^2-c_1}$$ that you are claiming? is this a property of absolute?

Comment: If you have any imaginary number, say, `x=2*I` then its absolute value is `Abs[x]=2`. If you have a function like `y=Sqrt[c-x^2]` and you only study it at `x>Sqrt[c]`, then at `x>Sqrt[c]` you can rewrite `y=Sqrt[c-x^2]=I*Sqrt[x^2-c]`. Therfore, if you are interested in the absolute value of such a function, you get `Abs[Sqrt[c-x^2]]=I*Sqrt[x^2-c]` which is only valid in the domain specified above. Anyway, the origin of your problem with the plot was the numerous application of `Abs` to a complex function during building the plot.